# My function for binary search returns None, I can't figure out why

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, search

I am implementing binary search in Python, I created a function for it but somehow, I am kinda stuck in between. My funtion returns "None" as the output and I can't figure out why it is doing that. My code here:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = 9

def bin_search(s_list, key):
    print(s_list)
    m = s_list[len(s_list)//2]
    if m == key:
        return 1
    elif m < key:
        bin_search(s_list[s_list.index(m)+1:],key)
    else:
        bin_search(s_list[0:s_list.index(m)],key)
```

print( bin_search(x, y))
It gives, the folowing output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[7, 8, 9, 10]
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the recursive calls make sure to `return` the values so they're passed up the stack to the caller. Just writing `bin_search(...)` ignores the return value.

```
if m == key:
    return 1
elif m < key:
    return bin_search(s_list[s_list.index(m)+1:],key)
else:
    return bin_search(s_list[0:s_list.index(m)],key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to @Greg's answer, that if you want to retuen `1` to main calling function then you should return your `return value` after recursion. Like:

```
def bin_search(s_list, key):
    print(s_list)
    m = s_list[len(s_list)//2]
    if m == key:
        return 1
    elif m < key:
        return bin_search(s_list[s_list.index(m)+1:],key)
    else :
        return bin_search(s_list[0:s_list.index(m)],key)

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = 7    
print( bin_search(x, y))
```

You should also handle for the condition of no key found.

Answer (score -1):

This is because your code is working as expected:

```
def bin_search(s_list, key):
    print(s_list)
    m = s_list[len(s_list)//2]
    if m == key:
        print('if')
        return 1
    elif m < key:
        print('elif')
        print(s_list[s_list.index(m)+1:])
        bin_search(s_list[s_list.index(m)+1:],key)
    else:
        print('else')
        print(s_list[0:s_list.index(m)])
        bin_search(s_list[0:s_list.index(m)],key)
```

Adding in debug prints helps to pinpoint what's going on.

```
print( bin_search(x, y)) 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
elif
[7, 8, 9, 10]
[7, 8, 9, 10]
if
None
```

So there is actually an instance where m==key.

Comment: But why there is 'None' ? That's what I can't understand.

Comment: That's the output of your function. It's never actually returning anything. It would, however, return something if you put "return" right before your bin_search commands.

Comment: The function doesn't actually return anything, because your "return 1" just returns to the parent level, and not to the original caller of "bin_search"